# How much access should an OS give to web-based scripting?

Tags: javascript, scripting, operating-system

I've been thinking about the access web-based applications have to an OS.

I'm curious:

1. What is the best way of determining
   this as it currently stands?
2. Is the trend leaning toward more, or
   less access?
3. What functionalities should be
   open/closed?

A simple example would be.. say your g-mail alerted you in the task-bar when an incoming e-mail is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, browsers have shown a strong tendency to prevent all manner of access to the operating system (and also the browser chrome). The fundamental risk is about trust and deception; if all you have done is visited a website, do you want it popping up dialog boxes or reading files on your hard drive? Even worse, you might not have visited the website on purpose; you might have been subject to a phishing attack where a spammy email linked you to a URL that looks like a popular site, but has a "1" instead of an "I".

It's nuanced to say which way the trend is going. In one sense, you can now do more than before, because you have the browsers enabling GPU support and, as part of HTML5, offline storage. All of this is being done with careful consideration of the security issues though, ensuring sandboxing takes place. On the other hand, you have browsers locking down on things like [cookies on the file:// URI](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535).

Many apps are increasingly web apps, but it's not as simple as just pointing to the web app in your browser. It might be an app you installed as a mobile web widget, or purchased in an app store like the Palm Pre's, where most apps are basically just web apps. The point is, the trust scenario is different in each case; I'd feel more confident giving certain OS access to an app from a reputable app store, where the code has been inspected, the producer has signed it, and the app's actions and privileges can be tracked ... than a random website I happened upon.

Answer (score 1):

Any access that is given is going to be abused by malware.  Guaranteed.

I think the trend is toward less access; consider Google's Chrome OS, in which you do all of your work within web applications, which have no native access to your system at all.